# .HTACCESS Rewrite Rule domain to /home

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

How can I redirect my *www.domain.com* to *www.domain.com/home* using htaccess?
I already have an existing htaccess file which handles my MVC.

I have the following htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]`
```

TIA

Answer (score 0):

just put this line below:

```
RewriteRule ^       /home    [L]
```

I am assuming that `/home` is either an directory or having other rewriterule for it.

Comment: thanks for the answer but this doesn't seem to work. I get a 500 internal server error whenever i add the line above.

Comment: that means you do not have `/home` defined

Comment: what it seems to me that you intend to do can be done with this code: `RewriteRule /home       index.php    [L]`. If you are talking about redirecting the page like loading a new `URL`, then you need to use `header()` function in PHP it cannot be done in `.htaccess`.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to mention that the home is inside a php file that is being handled by the index.php file.

Comment: Then above comment answer of mine will do the job

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by adding these lines of code

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$ [OR] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$ 
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.domain\.com\/home" [R=301,L]
```

Thanks for the help :)